# Caching and related Entries

Tags: templating, relations, cache

I'm currently working on integration some caching behaviour using [`{% cache %}`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/cache) tags. This works mostly just fine, but I have some issues when I work with related entries.

For example I have a list of categories with an indicator to show many entries they are assigned to.

- New (3)
- Used (2)
- Broken (3)

If I change an entry and add a category, the cache refreshes and shows the correct amount. But if I remove a category from an entry I get the wrong number until I refresh the cache manually.

Is this the expected behaviour? Or do I miss something here?

Here is my code example:

```
{% cache unless not craft.config.cache %}
{% set categorySlug = productSection ~ 'Categories' %}

<ul>

{% for category in craft.categories.group(categorySlug) %}
  {% set entryCount = craft.entries.relatedTo(category).total() %}
  {% if entryCount > 0 %}

    <li>
      {{ category.title }} ( {{ entryCount }} )
    </li>

  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

</ul>

{% endcache %}
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bug, and I think I know why. Can you try changing the `{% set entryCount ...` line to this?

```
{% set entryCount = craft.entries.relatedTo(category.id).total() %}
```

Comment: Sure, thanks. I get the same behaviour. Adding works, removing not.